# Change background color on Button click PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I m in middle of making a small code when a user clicks the button it will change the background color. So please have a look and let me know where i made a mistake.

(I m new to php)

```
    <html>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<?php
  if (isset ($_POST['color'])){
    $color = intval ($_POST['color']);
  } else {
    $color = "";
  }if ($color == 1){
    $fontcolor = "00FF00";
  } elseif ($color == 2){
    $fontcolor = "FF0000";
  } elseif ($color == 3){
    $fontcolor = "0000FF";
  } else {
    $fontcolor = "FFFFFF";
  }
  ?>
<body style="background-color: #<?php echo $fontcolor; ?>;"><?php
  ?>
  <div>
    <h1>Sample Excersise 1</h1>
    <p>sample text</p>
    <form action="" method="POST" ><input type="submit" value="Random"></form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must have a `<form>` tag around your button.

Comment: @syscall I already tried with the   <form action="" method="POST" ><input type="submit" value="Random"></form> but still didn't worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on seeing your code I think that you are trying to call the script from the same page itself. So in order to do that you can try with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
  if (isset ($_POST['color'])){
    $color =  $_POST['color'];
  } else {
    $color = "";
  }if ($color == 1){
    $fontColor = "00FF00";
    $fontStyle = "verdana";
  } elseif ($color == 2){
    $fontColor = "FF0000";
    $fontStyle = "courier";
  } elseif ($color == 3){
    $fontColor = "0000FF";
    $fontStyle = "Times New Roman";
  } else {
    $fontcolor = "FFFFFF";
  }
  ?>
  <script>
function customRandomFunction(min, max) {
     document.getElementById("hiddenValue").value
                      = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #<?php echo $fontColor; ?>;  font-family: <?php echo $fontStyle; ?>;"><?php
  ?>
  <div>
    <?php echo $fontColor; ?><!-- font color just for your reference -->
    <?php echo $fontStyle; ?><!-- font style just for your reference -->
    <h1 >sample Excersise 1</h1>
    <p>sample tex</p>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue"  name = "color" value="1"> 
  <input type = "submit" onclick = "customRandomFunction(1,3)">
</form>  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: value shoud be random on click.. whenever a click is done it will change the color

Comment: thanks a lot sir. it worked fine.. now if i want to change font too on every random click.. so what i have to do sir

Comment: Appreciate your time and help

Comment: pls chk the other ques  sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600638/php-count-wins-and-losses-in-rock-paper-scissor-game

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164483/discussion-between-bharathrao-and-thestark).