# PHP - Count Wins and Losses In Rock Paper Scissor Game

Tags: php

I have made a small code for the rock paper scissor game and it works perfectly fine for me. but I need to counts the wins, losses and draws on the final page with session.

I'm new to php and I'm unable to do so.

> Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <p>Please Choose Your Player</p>
    <h2>Rock<input type="radio" value="rock" name="playerturn"  /><br />
       Paper<input type="radio" value="paper" name="playerturn"  /><br />
       Scissors<input type="radio" value="scissors" name="playerturn" /><br />
    </h2>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Play"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Submit.php (Final Page)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
<?php
    if($_POST['playerturn']){

}

    else if(!$_POST['playerturn']){

}
        $playerturn = $_POST['playerturn'];
        $rpc= array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors');
        $rndm= rand(0,2);
        $Computer=$rpc[$rndm];

    echo '<h2>You picked: '.$playerturn.'</h2>';
    echo '<br /><br />';
    echo '<h2>The computer picked: '. $Computer .'</h2>';
  echo '<br /><br />';
    if($playerturn == $Computer){
    }
    if ($playerturn == $Computer){
    echo ' Draw  ';
    }
    else if($playerturn == 'rock ' && $Computer == 'scissors'){
    echo '<h1>You Win!</h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'rock' && $Computer == 'paper'){
    echo  '<h1>You Lose! </h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'scissors' && $Computer == 'rock'){
    echo  ' <h1>You Lose!</h1> ';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'scissors' && $Computer == 'paper'){
    echo '<h1> You Win! </h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'paper' && $Computer == 'rock'){
    echo '<h1>You Win!</h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'paper' && $Computer == 'scissors'){
    echo '<h1>You Lose!</h1>' ;
}

?>
<hr>
</br></br>
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='exc3.php'">Play Again</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Do we need to create a db and then it will work. or we can use session to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To use sessions in PHP, you'll need

```
session_start();
```

at the top of your PHP file.

Then, you may use $_SESSION as an associative array, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['my_wins'] = 99;
$_SESSION['cpu_wins'] = 8;
```

Comment: but i have to make a new function to count each win and lose right? i m new to php and already freaked out with this. any elaboration sir

Comment: You already have "You win" messages. You just need to add `$_SESSION['my_wins']++` when you've won and then list the number at the end of the game (same for cpu of course)

Comment: sir i have tried the method but its only printing the single win but not the every win. pls chk chk the updated code https://pastebin.com/q6F8XQFb

Comment: I've not tested your code but this line `$_SESSION['Win'] =0;` will set the variable to 0 every single time. You'll need something like `if (! isset($_SESSION['Win'])) {$_SESSION['Win'] =0;}` to check it exists first

Comment: I tried the if (! isset($_SESSION['Win'])) {$_SESSION['Win'] =0;} but i got several wins it only print 1 win everytime. 

Sir i request you to please test my code once. if possible

Comment: In pastebin.com/q6F8XQFb I replaced `$_SESSION['Win'] =0;` by `if ( ! isset($_SESSION['Win']) ) { $_SESSION['Win'] = 0; };` Now if `$_SESSION['Win']++` gets called (this does not work correctly every time, you'll need to check your code), $_SESSION['Win'] gets updated. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the working code for your game:

> gameStart.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['exit']) == 1){
session_destroy();
header('Location: gameStart.php');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
<form action="gameResult.php" method="POST">
    <p>Please Choose Your Player</p>
    <h2>Rock<input type="radio" value="rock" name="playerturn"  /><br />
       Paper<input type="radio" value="paper" name="playerturn"  /><br />
       Scissors<input type="radio" value="scissors" name="playerturn" /><br />
    </h2>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Play"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> gameResult.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['your_win'])  &&
    empty($_SESSION['cpu_win'])  && 
   empty($_SESSION['draw'])     ){
    $_SESSION['your_win'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['cpu_win'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['draw'] = 0;
    //Printing the initiation of session variables for your reference
    echo $_SESSION['your_win']; 
    echo $_SESSION['cpu_win'];
    echo $_SESSION['draw'] ;
}
    $playerturn = $_POST['playerturn'];
    $rpc= array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors');
    $rndm= rand(0,2);
    $Computer=$rpc[$rndm];

    echo '<h2>You picked: '.$playerturn.'</h2>';
    echo '<br /><br />';
    echo '<h2>The computer picked: '. $Computer .'</h2>';
  echo '<br /><br />';  
    if ($playerturn == $Computer){
        $_SESSION['draw']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ;
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>";
    }
    else if($playerturn == 'rock' && $Computer == 'scissors'){
        $_SESSION['your_win']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ;
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>";
        echo '<h1>You Win!</h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'rock' && $Computer == 'paper'){
        $_SESSION['cpu_win']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ;
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>";
        echo  '<h1>You Lose! </h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'scissors' && $Computer == 'rock'){
        $_SESSION['cpu_win']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ; 
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>"; 
        echo  ' <h1>You Lose!</h1> ';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'scissors' && $Computer == 'paper'){
        $_SESSION['your_win']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ;
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>";   
        echo '<h1> You Win! </h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'paper' && $Computer == 'rock'){
        $_SESSION['your_win']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ;
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>";
        echo '<h1>You Win!</h1>';
}
    else if($playerturn == 'paper' && $Computer == 'scissors'){
        $_SESSION['cpu_win']+=1;
        echo "YOUR SCORE:".$_SESSION['your_win']."<br>";
        echo "CPU SCORE:".$_SESSION['cpu_win']."<br>" ; 
        echo "DRAW:".$_SESSION['draw']."<br>";
        echo '<h1>You Lose!</h1>' ;
}

?>
<hr>
</br></br>
<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='gameStart.php'">Play Again</button><br>
<button type = "submit"><a href="gameStart.php?exit=1">EXIT</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please click the Exit option for properly destroying the session. Hope this will help you!!!.